# "This does not seem to be a Debug build" при запуске отладки

Tags: qt

Здравствуйте. При запуске отладки в qt creator получаю сообщение в окошке:

```
This does not seem to be a "Debug" build.
Setting breakpoints by file name and line number may fail.
Section .debug_info: Not Found.
Section .debug_abbrev: Not Found.
Section .debug_line: Not Found.
Section .debug_str: Not Found.
Section .debug_loc: Not Found.
Section .debug_range: Not Found.
Section .gdb_index: Not Found.
Section .note.gnu.build-id: Found.
Section .gnu.hash: Found.
Section .gnu_debuglink: Not Found.
```

Подскажите в чем может быть причина?

моя система Ubuntu 13.04 версия qt creator 2.7.0

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Там все в принципе написано - вы собрали приложение в релиз-версии, а потом попытались провести на ней отладку. Естественно, что релиз-версия не содержит сведений для отладки (причем не только себя - она даже dll другие использует - тоже собранные для отладки), о чем собственно вам иде и сообщила. Очистите проект (сборка - очистить проект) и запустите отладку снова установив сборку для отладки

Comment: выполнил
1) buil->clean all
2) debug->start debuging->start debuging

не помогло

Comment: скорее всего нужно еще цель сборки было поставить (я об этом кстати написал - см. конец сообщения) - слева снизу посмотрите над кнопками запуск\отладка\билд, там еще комп нарисован (если вы не для мобильного устройства конечно собираете), под ним должен стоять debug.

Comment: может дело в том что я использую cmake компилятор?

Comment: cmake к компиляции вроде отношения не имеет и сам собирать не умеет тоже, он служит для единого формата параметров проекта (где что искать, что компилить etc), который потом уже переделывается под существующие билдсистемы (msbuild, xcodebuild, make, eclipse cdt etc)